# Trouble implementing softmax activation and cross-entropy loss, and their derivatives in a neural net

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, softmax

I have implemented a simple multi-layer perceptron (with just 1 hidden layer) which can learn regression problems. I have written it so that the choice between sigmoid, tanh and relu activations can be specified. The squared error is then implemented as the loss function with each of these.

I now want to allow the choice to use the same model to learn multi-class classification problems, and so would like to implement the choice to use the softmax activation along with the cross-entropy loss. In my code below, the only changes that would need to be made (I hope) is to implement these in the `activation()` and `loss()` functions, and this should then work out of the box in both the forward pass and the backprop. This code runs a simulation of my model learning the XOR function, where the chosen activation function should be uncommented at the top.

However, I am really lost with implementing both of these functions, and even more so their derivatives. Any help and guidance is appreciated.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

activation = 'sigmoid'
# activation = 'tanh'
# activation = 'relu'
# activation = 'softmax'

numEpochs = 10000

class DataSet:

    def __init__(self, data, trainSplit=1):
        self.size = len(data)
        self.trainSize = int(self.size * trainSplit)
        self.testSize = self.size - self.trainSize
        self.inputs, self.labels = [], []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.inputs.append(data[i][0])
            self.labels.append(data[i][1])

        self.trainInputs = self.inputs[:self.trainSize]
        self.trainLabels = self.labels[:self.trainSize]
        self.testInputs = self.inputs[self.trainSize:]
        self.testLabels = self.labels[self.trainSize:]

        try:
            self.numInputs = len(self.inputs[0])
        except TypeError:
            self.numInputs = 1
        try:
            self.numOutputs = len(self.labels[0])
        except TypeError:
            self.numOutputs = 1


class MLP:

    def __init__(self, numInputs, numHidden, numOutputs, activationFunction):
        # MLP architecture sizes
        self.numInputs = numInputs
        self.numHidden = numHidden
        self.numOutputs = numOutputs

        self.activationFunction = activationFunction.lower()

        # MLP weights
        self.IH_weights = np.random.rand(numInputs, numHidden)      # Input -> Hidden
        self.HO_weights = np.random.rand(numHidden, numOutputs)     # Hidden -> Output

        # MLP biases
        self.IH_bias = np.zeros((1, numHidden))
        self.HO_bias = np.zeros((1, numOutputs))

        # Gradients corresponding to weight matrices computed during backprop
        self.IH_w_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.IH_weights)
        self.HO_w_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.HO_weights)

        # Gradients corresponding to biases computed during backprop
        self.IH_b_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.IH_bias)
        self.HO_b_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.HO_bias)

        # Input, hidden and output layer neuron values
        self.I = np.zeros(numInputs)    # Inputs
        self.L = np.zeros(numOutputs)   # Labels
        self.H = np.zeros(numHidden)    # Hidden
        self.O = np.zeros(numOutputs)   # Output

    def activation(self, x, derivative=False):
        if self.activationFunction == 'sigmoid':
            if derivative:
                return x * (1 - x)
            return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

        if self.activationFunction == 'tanh':
            if derivative:
                return 1 - np.tanh(x) ** 2
            return np.tanh(x)

        if self.activationFunction == 'relu':
            if derivative:
                return (x > 0).astype(float)
            return np.maximum(0, x)

        # TO DO ################################################################
        if self.activationFunction == 'softmax':
            if derivative:
                return 0
            return 0

        print("ERROR: Activation function not found.")
        sys.exit()

    def loss(self, labels, predictions, derivative=False):
        # TO DO ################################################################
        # Cross-Entropy
        if self.activationFunction == 'softmax':
            if derivative:
                return 0
            return 0
        # Squared Error
        else:
            if derivative:
                return (-2 * labels) + (2 * predictions)
            return (labels - predictions) ** 2

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # Ensure that inputs is a list
        try:
            len(inputs)
        except TypeError:
            inputs = [inputs]

        self.I = np.array(inputs).reshape(1, self.numInputs)
        self.H = self.I.dot(self.IH_weights) + self.IH_bias
        self.H = self.activation(self.H)
        self.O = self.H.dot(self.HO_weights) + self.HO_bias
        self.O = self.activation(self.O)

    def backwards(self, labels):
        # Ensure that labels is a list
        try:
            len(labels)
        except TypeError:
            labels = [labels]

        self.L = np.array(labels)
        self.O_error = self.loss(self.O, self.L)
        self.O_delta = self.loss(self.O, self.L, derivative=True) * self.activation(self.O, derivative=True)

        self.H_error = self.O_delta.dot(self.HO_weights.T)
        self.H_delta = self.H_error * self.activation(self.H, derivative=True)

        self.IH_w_gradients += self.I.T.dot(self.H_delta)
        self.HO_w_gradients += self.H.T.dot(self.O_delta)

        self.IH_b_gradients += self.H_delta
        self.HO_b_gradients += self.O_delta

        return self.O_error

    def updateWeights(self, learningRate):
        self.IH_weights += learningRate * self.IH_w_gradients
        self.HO_weights += learningRate * self.HO_w_gradients
        self.IH_bias += learningRate * self.IH_b_gradients
        self.HO_bias += learningRate * self.HO_b_gradients

        self.IH_w_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.IH_weights)
        self.HO_w_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.HO_weights)
        self.IH_b_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.IH_bias)
        self.HO_b_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.HO_bias)

    def process(self, data, train=False, learningRate=0):
        if train:
            size = data.trainSize
            inputs = data.trainInputs
            labels = data.trainLabels
        else:
            size = data.testSize
            inputs = data.testInputs
            labels = data.testLabels

        errors = []
        for i in range(size):
            self.forward(inputs[i])
            errors.append(self.backwards(labels[i]))
        if train:
            self.updateWeights(learningRate)
        return np.mean(errors)

data1 = DataSet([
    [[0, 0], 0],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], 0]
])

data2 = DataSet([
    [[0, 0], -1],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], -1]
])

data3 = DataSet([
    [[0, 0], [1, 0]],
    [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
    [[1, 0], [0, 1]],
    [[1, 1], [1, 0]]
])

if activation == 'sigmoid':
    data = data1
    mlp = MLP(data.numInputs, 2, data.numOutputs, 'sigmoid')
    learningRate = 1
if activation == 'tanh':
    data = data2
    mlp = MLP(data.numInputs, 2, data.numOutputs, 'tanh')
    learningRate = 0.1
if activation == 'relu':
    data = data1
    mlp = MLP(data.numInputs, 2, data.numOutputs, 'relu')
    learningRate = 0.001
if activation == 'softmax':
    data = data3
    mlp = MLP(data.numInputs, 2, data.numOutputs, 'softmax')
    learningRate = 0.01

################################################################################
# TO DO: UPDATE WEIGHTS AT INTERVALS, NOT EVERY EPOCH
################################################################################
losses = []
for epoch in range(numEpochs):
    epochLoss = mlp.process(data, train=True, learningRate=learningRate)
    losses.append(epochLoss)
    if epoch % 1000 == 0 or epoch == numEpochs - 1:
        print("EPOCH:", epoch)
        print("LOSS: ", epochLoss, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, softmax is not as easy as the other activation functions you have posted. For the activation function, you must calculate the exp(y_i) and then divide by the sum exp(y_k) for every y_k in Y. For the derivative, you must calculate every combination (n^2 combinations) of partial derivatives of every output wrt every input of the neuron. Luckily, the loss it is something a little bit easier to understand, since you can think about the softmax giving you some probabilities (so it resembles a probability distribution) and you calculate the Cross Entropy as is between the returned values and the target ones.